# Which site is the best to post question about Hiawatha and web host management?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I run a Linux based Hiawatha web server from home, and I often have related problems that come up. Most of the questions will be about configuration files, hosting multiple sites, and issues with my network router. The system is Crux linux based, and is accessed purely on ssh and sftp.

One such question would be "Setting up a virtual host always leads back to the default website. How do I fix this?"

Out of StackOverflow, Superuser, and Serverfault; which one should I post these questions on?

Edit: Added more information.

Comment: Thanks for asking here before posting the question. Could you please give us a few more details on the actual Hiawatha question, depending on the problems' specifics, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) could also be a suitable site.

Comment: I just updated the question with some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#questions) from **superuser**, seems to be the **right place** for a question related with software and general configuration issue:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking

---

At the Server Fault [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq#questions), it **declines** questions regarding

> Anything in a home setting

---

At stackoverflow [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), they expect:

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them

Comment: I would think (from looking at the faq) that [webmasters.se] would also be a good choice.